# Как отслеживать двойной тап по элементам в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

В моём приложении используется recyclerView. В каждой ячейке ленты отображаются посты пользователей. Там есть так же кнопки лайков. В лайауте для ячеек я задал на кнопке параметр onClick и в нём указал хендлер, который сработает в главной активити (которая задаёт адаптер для recyclerview), и уже там будет происходить обработка нажатия на лайк.

Т.е. получается onClick я задавал в лайауте, обработку в активити, а в адаптере я только лишь в тег задавал номер ячейки.

Я посмотрел в гугле и для реализации отслеживания двойного тапа используется GestureDetector и слушатель OnDoubleTap. Получается если я задам элементу слушателя в адаптере, то и обрабатывать нажатие надо в адаптере. А мне нужно делать обработку нажатия в активити.

Как мне реализовать отслеживание двойного тапа на ячейку recyclerview и вызвать определённый метод для обработки не в адаптере, а в активити (которая этот адаптер использует)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам для этого нужны интерфейсы. Порядок действий таков:

1. В нужный момент в адаптере срабатывает слушатель события какого-то.
2. В этом слушателе вызывайте метод интерфейса, ссылка на реализацию которого передана вами в адаптер.
3. В активити реализуйте этот интерфейс и передайте ссылку на него в адаптер.

Псевдо код:

```
class Adapter {
    //определяем интерфейс
    interface ClickListener {
         //этот метод будем вызывать из адаптера и выполнять в актвити
         void onClick();
    }

    //тут храним ссылку на реализацию вышеозначенного интерфейса
    ClickListener clickListener;

    //конечно же нам нужен сеттер
    public void setListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    //где-то когда-то произойдёт какое-то событие и в этот момент мы вызовем
    //метод интерфейса. Т.к. он определён в активити, то и выполнится он там
    //хоть и вызовется тут
    public void onBindViewHolder() {
        someView.setSomeEventListenerIETouch(touchEvent->clickListener.onClick());
    }
}


class Activity implements Adapter.ClickListener {

    //руализуем метод интерфейса
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
        Log.d("TAG", "click from adapter in activity");
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
        //передаём в адаптер ссылку на реализацию интерфейса
        adapter.setListener(this);
    }
}
```

---

Собственно точно так же вы можете реализовать слушатель тача в актвити и передавать его в адаптер.

Comment: Можно ли таким образом получать возвращаемое значение?

Comment: @Flippy, какое значение? Чем и как возвращемое? Вообще, создавая интерфейс вы можете в его методах задать параметры и вызывая этот метод передавать туда что-то. В итоге это что-то придёт в аргументы метода, реализованного в актвити

Comment: Это я прекрасно понял :)

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.