# Как использовать функцию, которая привязана к фрагменту, внутри адаптера RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Есть функция, которая вызывает определенный эффект вибрации:

```
public fun Fragment.vibratePhoneClick(){
    val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_TICK))
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(20)
    }
}
```

Я хочу использовать ее внутри обработчика нажатия, который находится в recyclerview (вынести обработчик в `onViewCreated` невозможно):

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(...) : ... {
    ...
    override fun onBindViewHolder(...){
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            vibratePhoneClick()
        }
    ...
}
```

Но студия выдает:

```
Unresolved reference. 
None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun Fragment.vibratePhoneClick(): Unit defined in com.example.kotlindiary in file MainFragment.kt
```

При этом, внутри метода `onViewCreated` эта функция срабатывает идеально

Я полагаю, вся соль как раз в том, что я объявляю функцию как `Fragment.vibratePhoneClick()`, а не `vibratePhoneClick()`, но тогда теряется контекст. Я сам не очень разбираюсь в том, как правильно применять контекст, но, вдруг, если кто-то знает толковую статью, был бы благодарен ссылке

Comment: Вам надо интерфейс в адаптер прокинуть, реализовав его во фрагменте. ПРимерный код тут есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644487/17609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз для вибро требуется `Context`, то лучше сделать основное расширение на `Context`

```
public fun Context.vibratePhoneClick() {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_TICK))
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(20)
    }
}

// расширение для фрагмента
public fun Fragment.vibratePhoneClick() = requireContext().vibratePhoneClick()
```

А `Context` можно получить из `View`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(...) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        it.context.vibratePhoneClick()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не обрабатывайте клик внутри адаптера. Это не его ответственность. Создайте интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface Listener {

    fun onClick(data: YourData) // если вам не нужны никакие аргументы - можете ничего не передавать
}
```

Реализуйте его внутри вашей Activity/Fragment. Передайте в ваш адаптер ссылку на него к примеру через конструктор (или метод сеттер):

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val listener: Listener) {

    ...
    override fun onBindViewHolder(...) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {listener.onClick(data[position])}
    }
}
```

И вызывайте спокойно в вашем фрагменте вашу функцию  `vibrator.vibrate(20)`